# OutputStream sound

Tags: java, android, input, java-output-stream

В моём приложении на андроид я использую несколько звуков с помощью класса soundpool,теперь я хочу реализовать функцию записи звука внутри своего приложения,как можно воспроизведение звуков перевести в массив byte для последующего вывода его в outputStream?